# Can web app listen() the websocket?

Tags: web-applications, websocket

I know websockets can connect to a somewhere listening server. But can your web app `listen()` on some port to become a server on it's own? If not websockets, is there any other HTML5 technology allowing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Even WebRTC data connections requires you to connect to a ICE/TURN/STUN server first to be able of communicate with other peers.

I am afraid there is not standard web technology that allows the app to become a server.